# If I redirect page wont load, if I reload the page then the page works

Tags: asp.net

```
Return Json(New retJQuery With {.retControl1 = "Item", .retView1 = "Index", .retHashURL = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(model.retHashURL), .retRedirect = true})
```

This is Login Controller.
I used redirect in Json, and it does not work at all and the menu is not changed.
But, if I reload my page, then its reloaded. Why doesn't it work well?